# Is it possible to have a List view that displays current users items?

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, office-365, list-view

We have a list in Sharepoint Online, this list have alot of items and over 50 users are creating items in that list.

Is it possible to make a list view that displays current users items? If so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes , you can by filter with `created by = [ME]`

- Modify your view from the above ribbon.
- At filter section select `Created By` equal to = `[ME]`

[image]

you can also adjust `Item-level Permissions`  at list setting > advanced setting > and set `Read items that were created by the user` as the following

[image]

Comment: Note that the second option isn't possible on all list types.

Comment: you are right as the issue tracker list , so I added the two solution :), because he do not mention the type of the list